# How to run a command on file in directory recursively creating a new file in each directory being visited (Bash)?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, grep

I have a directory with a few sub-directories.

```
.
├── alembic
│   └── results.csv
├── bigdata
│   └── results.csv
├── calchipan
│   └── results.csv
```

I'd like to create a copy of each `results.csv` file in the same directory named `results_cleaned.csv` where certain lines will be removed. Each sub-directory is known to contain only a single file, `results.csv`.

Running this on a single directory works:

```
find . -name 'results.csv' | xargs grep -v "Pattern" > results_cleaned.csv
```

However, running the same command on a root, produces just a single `results_cleaned.csv` file. I understand that I have to specify that I want to create a file in each sub directory individually, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `xarg` since all values are feed to single `grep`.
It would be better to iterate over each line of `find` (file names):

```sh
find . -name 'results.csv' | while read -r f
do
    grep -v "Pattern" "$f" > "$(dirname "$f")/results_cleaned.csv"
done
```

Comment: Gets the job done, thanks! What does `-r` do for the `read`? If this option is given, backslash does not act as an escape character?

Comment: https://ss64.com/bash/read.html `Backslash  does not act as an escape character.`